# Using JS to modify a style element with math operations

Tags: javascript, css, math

I am trying to use a JS sheet to make a button that when pressed, grows a square by 50 pixels (both height and width). I want to do this by a math operator (addition) and not by declaring a new value, so the button can be depressed multiple times.

This is for an exercise in combining multiple coding languages. I am allowed to change the HTML as needed to make it work. Also, the original exercise is just to make the button only work once (so setting a new pixel size works easily for that)

Here is the HTML and JavaScript I am working with:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", growByFifty);

function growByFifty() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.height += 50 + "px";
  document.getElementById("box").style.width += 50 + "px";
};
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width: 150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>
<button id="button1">Grow</button>
```

When the button is clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: You are telling it to concatenate the values. "50px", "50px50px", "50px50px50px" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "offsetHeight" you can get the height of the element.

Try this:

> document.getElementById("box").style.height  = document.getElementById("box").offsetHeight +50+'px'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `style.height` and `style.width` don't return the element's dimensions. You need to use offsetHeight and offsetWidth for that. I corrected your JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", growByFifty);

function growByFifty() {

    let currentHeight = document.getElementById("box").offsetHeight,
        currentWidth = document.getElementById("box").offsetWidth;

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = (currentHeight + 50) + "px"; 
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = (currentWidth + 50) + "px"; 
};
```